# Lua Arguments and Numbers

Tags: lua

```
function OnChat(PlayerId, Type, Message)

    if Message == "!usecarepackage" then
        if ReadKS1 == "CP" or ReadKS2 == "CP" or ReadKS3 == "CP" then
            InputConsole("msg %s has requested a care package!", Get_Player_Name_By_ID(pID))
            local pos = Get_Position(Get_GameObj(pID))
            pos:AssignY(pos:GetY()+1)
            building = Create_Object("SignalFlare_Gold_Phys3", pos)
            Attach_Script(building, "Test_Cinematic", "caredrop.txt")
            if building == nil then
                 InputConsole("ppage %d Cannot spawn Care Package here.", pID)
            elseif math.random(50, 64) == 50 then
                Attach_Script(building, "z_Set_Team", Get_Team(pID))
                Attach_Script(building, "M00_No_Falling_Damage_DME")
                --Add in rest of numbers and corresponding streak, such as UAV if math.random = 50
            end
        elseif ReadKS1 ~= "CP" or ReadKS2 ~= "CP" or ReadKS3 ~= "CP" then
            InputConsole("ppage %d You are not allowed to use that with your current streak selection", pID)
        end
    end

    return 1
end
```

I know this is scruffy code, but I'm receiving a "Bad argument #2 to 'format' (number expected, got no value)". This relates to this piece of code which prefixes all other pieces:

```
function InputConsole(...)
    Console_Input(string.format(unpack(arg)))
end
```

Finally, this is for the game Command and Conquer Renegade (should you wish to look up API etc). Any help in what I'm doing wrong would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The likely problem with this code is the use of the deprecated `arg` feature in your function `InputConsole()`. Lua 5.0 used `arg` as a way to access the actual arguments to a function declared as variadic using the `...` token in the argument list.

**Edit:** But likely doesn't mean correct.

The actual problem looks like the switch in idiom from `PlayerId` to `pID`. The former is the named parameter of the function `OnChat()`, while the latter is a global variable used in the function body without further initialization. Uninitialized globals are `nil`, so `nil` is passed to `InputConsole()` and the error message is telling you the truth.

#### Old answer that didn't solve it

Lua 5.1 deprecated that usage, and Lua 5.2 removed it entirely.

I'm not sure from the code fragments provided which version of Lua is actually used in this game, but the symptom is consistent with missing the automatically generated `arg` table.

I would write the function like this:

```
function InputConsole(...)
    Console_Input(string.format(...))
end
```

But you could also add `local arg = {...}` as the first line of the function and get much the same effect as provided by Lua 5.0 at the expense of creating (and discarding) the temporary table. The differences are subtle, and mostly have to do with the treatment of `nil` in tables.

For clarity, I would prefer name the first argument, as it is not really optional.

```
function InputConsole(fmt, ...)
    Console_Input(string.format(fmt, ...))
end
```

And if you can count on that argument being a string, that could be simplified further to

```
function InputConsole(fmt,...)
    Console_Input(fmt:format(...))
end
```

If its stringiness is of concern, just say `fmt = tostring(fmt)` or possibly `assert(type(fmt)=="string")` before the call to `Console_Input()`.

Comment: I ran it through the game and it just passed me the same error :/ This piece of code was working previously.

Comment: @HarryLudlow I think I spotted the actual problem. See my edit.

Comment: *doh* That would explain why all my commands stopped working when I switched from one OnChat to another! Thanks RBerteig - Next time I think I need to drink more coffee first.

Comment: But I just had four cups of coffee, and missed it. Sometimes even fresh eyes aren't quite enough to see.... :-)